# How to set alarms using alarm manager running every weekdays

Tags: android, android-alarms

Hey guys I'm using alarm manager to run my application at specific point of time. I want to run my application on every weekdays ( Mon-fri ) so could you please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to use the `AlarmManager` to trigger weekday based alarms.  As a workaround, can you trigger the alarm every day, then in your code check what day of the week it is, and only perform your actions on the days you require?

I'd be interested to hear any other approaches.

**EDIT**
Actually, could you set a daily alarm first.  Then when the alarm is triggered, check if the day is Friday.  If so, write a new alarm that will trigger on Monday.  When that goes off, create the daily alarm again.  Feels a bit clunky, but would cause the phone to wake up less.

You will need to handle the case when the user restarts their phone and ensure that any alarm that was set is recreated.

Comment: Thanks a lot dave this one is looking good ..i will surely want to use this as my backup option :)

Answer (score 1):

here is what needs to be done

- setup a Broadcast receiver to receive
  the event
- now schedule the event using Alarm
  Manager
- modify the previous receiver to start
  the app or activity

http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129

Comment: thanks Abhi....I am already using the thing which u mentioned but i am not able to run it on weekday basis:(

Comment: Check this implementation- http://sr-player.googlecode.com/svn-history/r166/trunk/SRPlayer/src/sr/player/SRPlayerAlarm.java